Dyanamic table creation in power automate
I want to create dyanamic table in power automation.
Table should be create automatically without giving any hard code.
I am trying multiple solutions but it cant work so help with the solution
I am currently using a power automatic cloud flow

this is the script for Dyanamic table creation - =OFFSET(Sheet1!A1,0,0,SUBTOTAL(103,Sheet1!$A:$A),3)
Sheet1 - excel sheet name
3 at end is - no of column in sheet
note - no blank row should be present in sheet
